# Proxy inside SOCKS 5 proxy

Tags: networking, ssh, security, proxy, socks-proxy

There's a secure LAN with a computer in it. This computer is configured with automatic proxy settings. A .pac file is used for this. With this automatic proxy configuration the computer can reach all web services inside the LAN. Without the proxy configuration only some web services can be reached.

[image: computer inside secure LAN]

I can connect to the computer inside the secure LAN from the outside using SSH. With this SSH connection I create a SOCKS 5 proxy. Using this SOCKS 5 proxy I can connect to web services inside the secure LAN from the outside. However, from the outside I can only reach the web services that are reachable without any .pac proxy config from the inside.

[image: socks proxy to secure computer inside secure LAN]

So, from the outside I can only reach the web services in the green box. The same web services I can reach from the inside if I don't have any automatic proxy configuration.

How do I use the proxy config from the .pac file from the computer outside the secure LAN, so that I from the outside can access all web services inside the secure LAN?